# The maximum value of determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Suppose we have a matrix $A_{3\times3} = (a_{ij})$, where $a_{ij}\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $|a_{ij}|\le 9$ for $1\le i,j\le 3$.

What is the maximum value may take the value $\det (A)$?

I'm looking for a reasonable solution without the use of brute-force.

Comment: I gave an answer with a dead end (now deleted), since it didn't work out for negative elements...

Comment: have a hypothesis that for such $n\times n$ mathix the max value is $2^{n-1}9^n.$

Comment: Sorry, the maximum determinant should be $9^3\times4$. One of the maximizers is the matrix filled with diagonal $-1$s and off-diagonal $1$s. The $9^3\times3\sqrt{3}$ bound is for *complex* matrices with entries inside the closed unit disc. For real matrices, non-integer solutions are path connected to integer solutions and hence the integer constraint will not lower the maximal determinant.

Comment: For a real or complex matrix I understand how to get the max value, but for an integer matrix I do not know how to prove, that $4\cdot 9^3$ is the maximum.

Comment: Yes, let's see if someone will post a non-brute-force proof.

Comment: Interesting is the geometric interpretation of the problem. We know |det(A)| is the volume of the parallelepiped defined by 3 vectors.

Comment: @Tzara_T'hong there are infinitely many $n$ such that $n \equiv 1 (\pmod 4)$ 
 and maximum value of deterrminant is $9^n (2n - 1)^{1 / 2} (n - 1)^{(n - 1) / 2}$. See theorem A in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379596001474 and combine it with the first part of user1551's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by no means a concise answer, but we can at least avoid using brute force.

It is well known that for $[-1,1]$-matrices (i.e. *real* matrices with all its entries lying inside the closed interval $[-1,1]$), the maximal determinant is always attainable with a $\{-1,1\}$-matrix (i.e. an integer matrix whose entries are $-1$ or $1$). The reason is that if $A$ is a maximizer and some $a_{ij}$ lies in the interior of the interval, its corresponding minor must be zero. Therefore, it doesn't matter what the exact value of $a_{ij}$ is, and one may move it to the interval's boundary. Move the entries in the interior to the boundary one by one, you get a maximizer $A$ of which all entries lie on the boundary.

So, in your case, the maximizer is just $9$ times the maximizer of the determinant of all $\{-1,1\}$ matrices (and the determinant of the former is $9^3$ times the maximal determinant of the latter). Let $A$ be a maximizer of the latter. As the value of $|\det A|$ is unaffected by left/right multiplication of $A$ by diagonal matrices with diagonal entries taken from $\{-1,1\}$, we may assume that
$$
A=\pmatrix{-1&1&1\\ 1&a&b\\ 1&c&d}
$$
where $a,b,c,d\in\{-1,1\}$ and we want to maximize $|\det A|=|(a+1)(d+1)-(b+1)(c+1)|$. By swapping the last two columns of $A$ if necessary, we may further assume that
$$
\det A=(b+1)(c+1)-(a+1)(d+1)\ge0.
$$
Since all bracketed terms in the above are either $2$ or $0$, the maximal determinant occurs when $b+1=c+1=2$ and $(a+1)(d+1)=0$, i.e. when $b=c=1$ and $a$ or $d$ or both are equal to $-1$. Hence the maximum determinant is $4$ and the answer to your original problem is $9^3\times 4$.

Comment: Nice solution! Thank you!